# ALSA input from MIDI keyboard

Tags: midi, libalsa

I'm writing a software synth in Linux using libasound. I want to control it with a MIDI keyboard.

I have some working code using snd_seq_open() and snd_seq_event_input() but it only creates a virtual MIDI port. I have to go to the commandline and type "aconnect 20 128" to route the MIDI data to my app.

How can I get my code to either set up the connection by itself or connect directly to the MIDI hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the connection with a function like [snd_seq_connect_from()](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___seq_middle.html#ga1382029795fa101a3b8cc0af7b83b639).

See, for example, the [aseqdump source code](https://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=blob;f=seq/aseqdump/aseqdump.c;hb=HEAD).